# Network connection in terminal is too slow

Tags: internet, gnome-terminal

I am running an Wi-Fi connection of our university residential hall. When I browse Internet or Download something it is about 300 kBps speed.

But in the terminal the connection is too slow and gets slower & then gradually tends to 0 kBps i.e. "No Internet".
In average I get about 4kBps speed for any case.
apt update, wget, curl, composer --- all are so slow that cannot complete even "apt-get update" command.

Before, this problem did not occur but recently, I am very upset now.

I cannot install anything from terminal.
N. B. Firewall is disabled as default.

Comment: What happens if you let a `ping` any site run for a few minutes? Do the responses get longer and longer?

Comment: Use `grep` to search the `/var/log/kern.log*` files for mentions of your wireless adapter. `iwconfig` will show you this name.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to change the mirror from which you gets the data.
go to ***Software & Update*** --> select *Download from: **other*** --> choose *select the **best server***/ or the server you prefer! cheers:)